# Removing a point from a closed mapping.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and closed surjection.

Suppose $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ are such that $f^{-1} \{y\}=\{x\}$.

Then $f\restriction _{X\setminus \{x\}}:X\setminus \{x\}\to Y\setminus \{y\}$.

We know $f\restriction _{X\setminus \{x\}}$ is a continuous surjection. Is it closed? What if we assume $X$ and $Y$ are compact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, to get a function that is well-defined you have to remove all of $f^{-1}(y)$ from $X$. Once you have done that, let $C\subset X-f^{-1}(y)$ be closed, then $C=D\cap(X-f^{-1}(y))$ for some closed set $D\subset X$, and we have:
$$f(C)=f(D\cap(X-f^{-1}(y)))=f(D)\cap(Y-y)$$
which is a closed subset of $Y-y$. Thus the restricted map is closed.